# Character entry causing infinite loop in C

Tags: c, infinite-loop

Ok, so I've searched several places for an answer to this, and I found the answer to the same problem in `C++`, but it involved clearing `cin` and that stuff, and I'm not sure how to translate that to `C`. I apologize in advance if this was, in fact, answered somewhere else, and I just missed it. Also, keep in mind that I'm basically teaching myself `C`, and I don't know much beyond what you see in this code.

Basically, my problem is this: I am running a loop that asks for input and then uses a `switch` statement to choose what happens. The `switch` takes an `int`, and it works fine with any numerical entry. When you enter a `char`, however, it just loops infinitely, giving no chance to input anything else.

Assuming this is the same problem as it was in the `C++` examples I looked up - and I'm not 100% sure it is - when I enter a `char` it gets added to the buffer, and never gets cleared, so each time it loops the invalid input gets used again. Clearing the buffer seemed simple enough in `C++`, but I was unable to find anything I could understand in `C`.

Here's my code, for reference:

```
int main()
{


  while(1)
  {
    printf("(1-10) -> Run a program | (-1) -> Display menu | (0) -> Quit : ");

    int quit = 0;
    int select;
    scanf("%d", &select);
    switch(select)
    {
      case 1:
        printf("%s", pgmRun);
        helloWorld();
        printf("%s", pgmEnd);
        break;

      //More cases here

      case 0:
        quit = 1;
        break;
      default:
        printf("\n");
        printf("Error: Invalid input\n");
        printf("\n");
    }

    if(quit == 1)
      break;
  }
return 0;
}
```

Thanks in advance for your help, and sorry for such a lengthy post. I tend to be long-winded. :P

Comment: I suggest you [read more about `scanf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf), especially check what it returns.

Comment: @Floris Technically speaking, `fflush(stdin)` is undefined behavior. Not all libraries support it. Might be better to get characters until newline.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`fflush(stdin)` has undefined behavior. If you want to discard characters entered after the scanf() call, you can read and discard them.
You can use `getchar()` to clear the character.

Comment: You are right; I was too quick and should have tested my suggestion.

Comment: For completeness, I suggest you edit your answer to show how to use `getchar()` - for example with `while(scanf("%d", &select)!=1) getchar();` .

Comment: What I did was insert `getchar()` into the loop after the `switch` statement.

Comment: alternatively, read until you get `\n` or `EOF`, in many cases it makes more sense to discard the rest of the line, if the current line had garbage.